# Get 2 values from one columns with different criterias?

Tags: sql, select

I have 2 tables, players and bans.

```
players = id, name

bans = id, type, banned_id, accuser_id
```

How do I select both banned and accusing player names in one row? Here's my wrong code:

```
SELECT `bans`.`id`, `players`.`name` AS `banned`, `players`.`name` AS `accuser`
FROM `bans`, `players`
WHERE `bans`.`type` = 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get data about banned users only

```
SELECT b.id, p.name as accuser FROM bans b JOIN players p  ON p.id=b.accuser_id WHERE b.type=2
```

If you want to get data about all users with info about bans

```
SELECT * FROM players p LEFT JOIN bans b ON b.accuser_id = p.id
```